# Android - Manipulate scrollview

Tags: android, scrollview

all I want to do is to scroll to a specific position.
I found this method which scrolls the scrollview (horizontal) to the fullest right:

```
scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT);
```

I want to be able to scroll to the fullest right minus 10px, how can achieve this? Anyway to manipulate scrollview to scroll to specific position?

Really need this, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **ScrollView.scrollTo(Xpos,Ypos)** to scroll to a specific location or **ScrollView.scrollBy(xPos, Ypos)** to scroll by a specific distance

To scroll to the end of the view - 10px you can write

working:

```
ScrollView.scrollTo(ScrollView.computeHorizontalScrollRange() - 10, 0);
```

not working:

```
ScrollView.scrollTo(ScrollView.getWidth() - 10, 0);
```

Comment: Yeah man, this solution works, only one thing more (I will accept your answer anyway). How to detect when horizontalscroll has scrolled to the fullest right?

Comment: scrollView.getWidth() will not give you the scroll width, it will give you the widgets width.

Comment: I have 5 tabs in my tabwidget, i need to calculate the length of all the five tabs, right? And then minus 10 px?

Comment: ya i believe that Joe was right. you can use computeHorizontalScrollRange() insted of getWidth().

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT);
scrollView.scrollBy(-10, 0);
```